# Comparing DateTime with ASP.NET MVC and SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, sql-server-ce

I am trying to create a strongly-typed model and view. This portion of code is supposed to return a list of "emails" sent in a contact-us form.

I want to return all form submissions sent today. The SQL Server 2008 datatype is `datetime`. So I have a `DateTime` field in my model.

```
public ActionResult ResultTable()
{
    CombinedReport report = new CombinedReport();

    report.emails = report.db.ContactEmails.Where(w => w.FormInserted.Equals(DateTime.Today)).ToList();
    return PartialView(report);
}
```

When I ran this configured for the local built-in SQL Server CE, it worked fine.

When I set it up for our actual database running SQL Server 2008, it doesn't work.

With some trial-and-error, and looking at code in other parts of my program, I noticed that the C# implementation of `DateTime` is including `12:00:00AM` as a part of the date, and when it's doing the comparison to SQL, it's sending that exact time in.

It won't let me compare a `DateTime` to a string, so I can't even format "today" as a string.

The CombinedReport model I instantiate here is just a view model for a specific page and doesn't directly map to a database ("ContactEmails" does).

What is the best way to go forward that will let me keep a strongly-type view and model?

Comment: Look at using Convert.ToDateTime to get your string date + string time into one datetime

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to compare the *date* part of the value, you should make that explicit:

```
DateTime today = DateTime.Today;
report.emails = report.db.ContactEmails
                         .Where(w => w.FormInserted.Date == today)
                         .ToList();
```

Now whether the flavour of LINQ you're using supports the `Date` property is a different matter - but that's what I'd try to start with.

Comment: I'm using whatever the default LINQ implementation is with VS2008 and MVC3. It doesn't appear to support the Date property

Comment: @coreno: I don't believe there's any such thing as a "default LINQ implementation" - you should know whether you're using LINQ to SQL or the Entity Framework.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using EF, use the [`EntityFunctions.TruncateTime`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.entityfunctions.truncatetime.aspx) method:

```
.Where(w => EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(w.FormInserted).Equals(DateTime.Today))
```